# Can additional symbols be added to the circuit button?

Tags: feature-request

If there is a way to add more symbols in the circuit editor, I think a motor symbol would be appropriate. There may be additional symbols people would want. Is this possible? Is it difficult?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I agree that a Motor symbol has been missing, this will end up in the todo of CircuitLab people (which it should, though I personally don't know how), so I have resigned long ago to use Lamp symbols for that with the note "This is a Motor"

Comment: Yeah, I know how todo lists work :) I did the workaround with an inductor. Its nice to know its on a list.

Comment: Doesn't CircuitLab let you draw your own symbol?  If not that would be a serious failing, making it hard to believe.  And no, if you mean motor draw a motor, not a lamp or something else.  It's very annoying to analyze a circuit where you are told "this opamp isn't really a 741", "that transistor is really a N channel FET, not a NPN", etc.  I routinely downvote and vote to close such things.  It's really rude to dump something like that on the volunteers you are asking for free help from.  It your job to provide a clear schematic.  There is no excuse.  Use whatever tools you need to.

Comment: @OlinLathrop Unless you want your motor symbol to be a square with pins on the sides: No you cannot draw your own motor symbol. I would add a motor symbol if I could, but I'm not in the habit of taking screenshots of Altium just for answering a question. It's either built-in, or shady, hard to follow text, where built in has no motor, so I make do when _I Am Answering_. I have not in my life asked a question here, but you know what, I'd still do it that way if I did, because it's the only one there is.

Comment: You get more slack when answering instead of asking.  My comment above was for asking.  If the built-in tool doesn't have a motor, then I agree you can substitute something in a answer.  However, I strongly disagree that this is OK when asking.  Your job when asking is to provide a good schematic.  The built-in circuit editor is certainly not the only choice.  Use whatever tools you want, we don't care how you arrive at a clear schematic, only that you do.  I haven't used the built-in schematic editor yet, and I've posted many schematics.  Askers have plenty of options.

Comment: The circuit tool is my go to for answering, since it is used for documentation purposes more than circuit simulation purposes (at least from what I've seen). It would be NICE not essential, to have some additional circuit symbols, that's why I asked. It doesn't hurt to ask.

Answer (score 0):

What are the key pieces of information with respect to a motor that is needed when analysing a circuit & its control.

1. terminal inductance
2. terminal resistance
3. BackEMF

inductors, resistors, AC & DC voltage sources are available as is annotation. Just stating a load is a motor really doesn't help with circuit or control analysis.

Comment: It helps because at least half of the time people are using the circuit tool to draw a circuit for documentation purposes only